# How to create a folder using substring of filename

Tags: batch-file, dos, subdirectory

I need to create a batch file to create a folder from substring of a filename
example filename : txt_abc_123 
create a folder with the name between "_"  (abc)
and the filename with (123)

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this for Windows or MS-DOS?

Answer (score 0):

look into the help for `FOR /F`, something like `FOR /F "tokens=2,3* delims=_" %%a in ("txt_abc_123 ")` will yield abc in %%a and 123 in %%b.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you only have two underscores in the filename, here's a solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set xfile=txt_abc_123
set n=0
set zz=0
set before=
set file=
set folder=
:begin
set yy=!xfile:~%n%,1!
set /a n=n+1
if "%yy%"=="_" (
  if %zz% EQU 0 (
    set zz=1
  ) ELSE (
    set zz=2
  )
)
if %zz% EQU 0 (
  set before=%before%%yy%
)
if %zz% EQU 1 (
  if not "%yy%"=="_" (
    set folder=%folder%%yy%
  )
)
if %zz% EQU 2 (
  if not "%yy%"=="_" (
    set file=%file%%yy%
  )
)

if not "%yy%"=="" (
  goto begin
)

echo Folder: %folder%
echo File:   %file%

if not exist %folder%\ (md %folder%)
move %xfile% %folder%\%file%

endlocal
```

If you don't know you'll have only two underscores, this would need to be modified slightly.

If you want to run this for multiple files, replace the `txt_abc_123` above with `%1` , save to file batchfilename.bat, and run with

```
for %i in (*_*_*) do (
  batchfilename.bat %i
)
```